# C - passing argument 1 of 'send_data' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, char

Im writing uart code for a microcontroller. My code is working fine with passing string("..."), but giving problem when i try to passing the char('.'). Yes, it is i've declared "s" a pointer for string, but there is a chance of passing char value. Is there any possibilities to pass both string and char values in **send_data**?

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void send_data( char *s)
{
    while(*s!='\0')
    {
        send_dt1(*s);
        s++;
    }
}

void send_dt1( char in_c)
{
   printf("%c",in_c);
}

int main(void)
{
    send_data("sample_data"); //fine
    send_data('Q'); //warning, no data displaying
  return 0; /* terminate the program */
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: Hi @CoolGuy Thanks for the reply. I tried that, i think "Q" is too a string only, i need to pass 'Q'. My question will hurt a little i think...

Comment: Your function expects a pointer to the first character of a null-terminated string. `'Q'` is a character literal. It is not a pointer and it is not a null-terminated string.

Comment: @cad - on a microcontroller, there are no "segfaults".  It may, however, depending on architecture read until it runs into a memory region that raises an interrupt/fault that (at best) might be handled by rebooting the MCU.  Even on a system running a full OS, segfaults are not guaranteed.  In fact, i might go as far as to say its *more* likely you would run into a zero that the end of a readable memory page/region.

Answer (score 3):

As `send_data` expects `s` to be a **null-terminated** string anyway, I would just recommend using a string:

```
send_data("Q");
```

---

Notes:

- you should pass a `const char*` around as long as you don't modify the string at `s`

Answer (score 3):

```
 send_data('Q'); //warning, no data displaying
```

Don't pass character to it . It expects a `char *` .

You can do this -

```
 send_data("Q");
```

Also you should declare a prototype for function `void send_dt1( char in_c)` as you make a call to it before it's definition in function `void send_data( char *s)` .

This will also generate warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a `char` to a function that expects a `char *`.

If you really need to be able to pass both, you'll need another function to accept a `char` and put it in a string so that `send_data` can be called:

```
void send_char_data(char c)
{
    char s[2];
    s[0] = c;
    s[1] = '\0';
    send_data(s);
}

....

int main(void)
{
    send_data("sample_data");
    send_char_data('Q');
  return 0;
}
```